# read a .csv file stored on another computer in xcode

Tags: objective-c, sockets, data-transfer

My data is stored in the form of a .csv file on another computer, which is like an office server. I am developing an iphone app that requires to read this data during runtime. Note that I can easily parse a csv file given its stored on my system.

As far as I know Java uses socket programming for this. I know there must be a similar provision in Objective C. Please guide me as to what class in Xcode can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a web service in the office server and hit the url for fetching the data. Use `NSURLConnection` for this.

Comment: but i have to load data from a file on another computer and not internet

Comment: Aren't they connected through LAN ? For you to transfer the files there has to be some sort of network connection between the computers right?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit as to what do you mean by setting up a web service? And does the url mean the address of the machine plus the file location in it ?? Please give me a sample example as to how to set such a URL..

Comment: Is the other system a mac? If yes, then there is already a free web server set-up for you.

Comment: no dude, the other system is a windows. Can you please help me sending a link or something for both the mac and windows

Comment: You have to first set up a web server (like apache, tomcat) on the windows machine and then keep your document in the appropriate folder. Then you can access it using your machine name and file name appended to it with protocol as http. I am not very familiar with web services as such. But that is the gist of it, i think.

Comment: You could alternatively setup a ftp server maybe or even mount the windows volume as smb and then access it.